# How to add tabbar in cameraView of zbar sdk

Tags: iphone

I'm a newbie in iphone app developing, I just started learning two weeks ago due to the need of my final project.
So please forgive me if my question seems really stupid.

I've searched in forums and zbar documentation about how to customize the cameraView.
But I still didn't have a clear understanding about how to do it.

Now I'm trying to add tabbar into the cameraView, could anybody tell me how to do it?

I know that I need to use overlay and create my own view, adding the reader as a subview in it. Could anybody give me some direction more explicitly about how to reaise it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own custom UITabBarController class. And add this controller in your custom camera view. and custom camera view is created by  the AVFoundation framework.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you need to add the tabbar to the appDelegate and then inner views within each tab. Therefore you would have within the appdelegate `applicationDidFinishLoading` method

```
 // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

of course, you need to declare it in the **appdelegate.h** file

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

Search for tabBar tutorials. They must be created BEFORE any NAVIGATION Controller.

Then place all your zbar code in the first view controller.